# MPMoviePlayerController doesn't display video

Tags: ios, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller

I saw a lot of topics there and always the same problem: it's not displaying at all.

So because I am little stubborn, I want **it more**

This is my code :

```
let moviePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("back", ofType:"mp4");
println(moviePath!)
let movieURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(moviePath!)
let theMoviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: movieURL!)
self.view.addSubview(theMoviePlayer.view)
theMoviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
theMoviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = true
theMoviePlayer.fullscreen = true
theMoviePlayer.play()
```

I checked and I have the movie file in the app's bundle resources.
The video dimension : 640 × 360 pixels

So where it can be from?

Did I forget something important ?

**Edit**

This new code works but always some problems :

```
let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("back", withExtension: ".mp4")
let player = MPMoviePlayerViewController(contentURL: url)
presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated(player)
player.moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
player.moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatMode.One
player.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = true
player.moviePlayer.play()
```

It show me the video in landscape view and not full screen.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it in one of my apps. You might need to call presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated() and pass in the MPMoviePlayerViewController instead of doing addSubview.

```
let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("back", withExtension: ".mp4")
let player = MPMoviePlayerViewController(contentURL: url)
presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated(player)
player.prepareToPlay()
player.shouldAutoplay = true
player.fullscreen = true 
player.moviePlayer.play()
```

Comment: Thanks you. But it's not in full screen and it's in landscape mode. DO you have any solutions about that ?

Comment: I believe that is because you are setting `player.fullscreen = true`. That makes the video play in landscape mode by default.

Comment: Nop it's not the problem :s

Answer (score 0):

** Resolved **

I resolved addend the line :

```
player.moviePlayer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI / 2))
```

Of course, it do a rotation of the video. So If it's a simple background animated like clouds or something simple, it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

if there is no issue with the content type of video, call below function. It just works. :)

private func presentVideoVC(){

```
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v")!
    var moviePlayerVC: MPMoviePlayerViewController! = MPMoviePlayerViewController(contentURL: url)
    self.presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated(moviePlayerVC)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

my two cents:

in case of ios9 use https.. (or add exceptions... not good.)
dont call directly on viewDidload, it does not work, call in async to wait some time, allowing controller to be set:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
    self.playIt()           
}


func playIt() {
    let urlString = "https://www.ingconti.com/softysit/Spinelli_short.mp4"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlString)!
    let moviePlayerVC: MPMoviePlayerViewController! = MPMoviePlayerViewController(contentURL: url)
    moviePlayerVC.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = true
    self.presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated(moviePlayerVC)
}
```

note that now MPMoviePlayerViewController is deprecated.